# autodesk-forge add hyperlink to object in a360 viewer

Tags: hyperlink, autodesk-forge

Need to find way to add hyperlinks to components of an assembly in the a360 viewer such that, when clicked or touched with mobile device, will navigate to a web page for more information.  Realize it requires Forge API but can't find any specific examples of such a solution.  I think this can be done from a properties table but I want direct navigation from touching/clicking the object.

Comment: When you say "a360 viewer" you mean the Viewer instance used on the A360 website? That is not customizable. If you want a customized version then you would have to embed the same Viewer in your own website.

Comment: Thanks Adam for your response.  We plan to embed the viewer on our website.  We want visitors to be able to explode an assembly and click on (or touch for mobile) components to hyperlink to a webpage for additional info.  Not sure where to start in learning how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You could just subscribe to the object selection event and react to it by e.g. opening a given URL:

```js
    viewer.addEventListener(
        Autodesk.Viewing.SELECTION_CHANGED_EVENT,
        function (event) {
            // Get id of first selected item
            var dbId = event.dbIdArray[0];
            if (dbId) {
                // Maybe get the properties of the selected object
                viewer.getProperties(dbId, function (props) {
                   // Depending on the properties you could open a website
                   
                   // Just printing to the console the external id of 
                   // the selected component as an example
                   console.log(props.externalId);
                });
            }
        }
    );
```

If you search for "Autodesk.Viewing.SELECTION_CHANGED_EVENT" you can find some articles and samples also using this event, e.g. https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/selection-override